CSL style following APA 7th Edition and providing a superscript and a full footnote for every citation
Is there a CSL (Citation Style Language) style that follows APA (American Psychological Association) 7th Edition, and provides a superscript and a full footnote reference for every citation? An example of the intended result is available at https://evelinaleivada.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/10/if-part-b-document-1_diva.pdf
The closest style I have found is this one, but it groups citations into a single number when there is more than one at the end of a sentence. I tried to modify this style using ChatGPT, but to no avail.

What is CSL? What is APA?

Thank you for the nudge. Added full names.

It is not possible with current CSL. See https://forums.zotero.org/discussion/116373/csl-style-following-apa-7th-edition-and-providing-superscript-and-full-footnote-for-every-citation#latest
